# How can I link a profile page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profile

I'm currently building a marketplace with Ruby on Rails. Right now I'm trying to build a profile page with devise (based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEkpwM-GvMQ) .
For devise I've created the user model.
For the profile page I've created the users controller.
For the marketplace I've created the scaffold page(pages).
Every user has a id and the profile page is basically based on that id.
**Does somebody know how I can link somebodys profile page in his navbar?**

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_pages = @user.pages
  end

end
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb (basically the navbar)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <header>
            <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand" style="background-color: #B1D3FE;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../pages"><%= image_tag("navbar/logo.png") %></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto ">
            </ul>

            <% if !user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="nav-item list-unstyled" >
                <%= link_to 'Login/Register', new_user_session_path, class:"btn", style:"background-color: #00188A; color: white;" %>
            </li>
            <% end %>

            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown list-unstyled me-5">
              <a class=" btn nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #00188A; color: white;">
              Profile
              </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li>
                      
                      <%= link_to "My Profile",  users_path , class:" dropdown-item" %>
                                      
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class:" dropdown-item" %>
                    </li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path, class:" dropdown-item" %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:" dropdown-item" %>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <% end %>

          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

  </header>

  <body>
       



<% if notice %>
          <%= render 'layouts/alerts' %>
<% end %>


 <%= yield %>
```

app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
    <%= @user.email %>

<% @user_pages.each do |pages| %>
    <%= link_to pages.title, page_path(pages) %>
<% end %>
```

app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :pages
  resources :users
  root to: 'pages#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

When I clicK on the My-Profile link on the navbar (`<%= link_to "My Profile",  users_path , class:" dropdown-item" %>`) I land on this page:
[profile page bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzRfn.png)

Thank you for reading. It would help me allot if somebody would know how to fix this.

Comment: need to go to the page for the current user `user_path(current_user)` instead of users_path which would show all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `users_path` links to the index page which shows all the users. The reason you are seeing the error is because you only have the `show` action setup in the controller. To link to a specific users profile page, you would link to the show path which would be `user_path(@user)`. You need to pass the `@user` in order for rails to know which user to show on the page.

The link would look something like this:

```
<%= link_to "My Profile", user_path(@user), class:" dropdown-item" %>
```